# What is the -a in the find command

Tags: find

```
find . -a -type f -a -name '*.txt'
```

I thought the -a acts as an "&" between tests. Like 'expr1 & expr2 & expr3'. Why does it work fine if I add a '-a' between the path and the first expression?

Comment: GNU findutils vs. BSD find. This isn't really a shell-related question. If you install GNU find from MacPorts or summat, you would probably get the same error as on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

```
   expr1 expr2
      Two expressions in a row are taken to be joined with an  implied
      "and"; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is false.

   expr1 -a expr2
      Same as expr1 expr2.
```

In the case of the path and the expression, I'm guessing it's just a parsing quirk that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

*and* is the default, so I would guess that `-a` is simply ignored and no attempt is made to parse it consistently.